# How do I apply a docker run with --config option to docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, snowplow

I have the following docker command:

```
sudo docker run --env-file env.list \
  -p 80:8080 \
  -v $PWD/snowplow/config:/snowplow/config  \
  snowplow/scala-stream-collector-kinesis:1.0.0  \
  --config /snowplow/config/config.hocon
```

I'm trying to move this into a `docker-compose.yml` file but I'm having issues with the --config option. My file looks like this, can anyone see where I am going wrong:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  collector:
    image: snowplow/scala-stream-collector-kinesis:1.0.0
    environment:
      - AWS_CBOR_DISABLE=1
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    volumes:                                                                                                  
      - ./data/snowplow:/snowplow
    configs:
      - source: collectorcnf                                                                                    
        target: /snowplow/config/config.hocon          
configs:
  collectorcnf:
    file: ./data/snowplow/config/config.hocon
```

I've moved the config file accordingly to match. The error message I am getting  on `sudo docker-compose up` is:

```
collector_1  | Error: Missing option --config
collector_1  | Try --help for more information.
collector_1  | configuration has no "collector" path
```

Comment: The above error is when you run the `docker-compose up`?

Comment: yes, it is on `sudo docker-compose up`. This is under Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Do you get some `WARNING` similar to this: `WARNING: Some services (collector) use the 'configs' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'configs' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.`

Comment: Yes, but I cannot make sense of how to resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything that appears after an image name is overriding the image default command. So you want:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  collector:
    image: snowplow/scala-stream-collector-kinesis:1.0.0
    # the below "command" is the portion after the image name in the run command:
    command: ["--config", "/snowplow/config/config.hocon"]
    environment:
      - AWS_CBOR_DISABLE=1
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./data/snowplow:/snowplow
```

When an image has an entrypoint defined, the command is appended after the entrypoint to become arguments to the command. Using json formatting is important to avoid this being wrapped in a `/bin/sh -c "..."` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the `--config` with the `docker` command and `configs` in `docker-compose` point two separate things.

The `configs` option in the compose file is for `docker config` which is used for setting service config. See more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/config/). This plays nicely with `docker swarm` and while running docker services.

On the other hand, the `--config` option is specifically for the docker client config i.e. the file under `.docker` directory. More details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files).

**Note:** I can see why this naming is super confusing. There is a warning issued when you run `docker-compose up` with `configs` which hints at `configs` - excerpt below (based on your `collector` tag):

```
WARNING: Some services (collector) use the 'configs' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'configs' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.
```